# Casebox object field depending on another field in the same parent object

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I have a CaseBox object, with one field (`age`) intended to depend on another field (`birthdate`).  As I understand the developer docs, I should make `age` of type `Objects`, write a server-side function, and set the `config` property's `source` element on `age` to pass the function and field.

My config for the `age` field:

```
{
   "source": {
      "requiredFields": "birthdate"
      ,"fn":"Casebox\\CoreBundle\\Service\\Util\\Utility.calculateAge"
   }
   ,"readOnly": "true"
   ,"autoLoad": "true"
}
```

I have independently validated `calculateAge()`; it accepts a scalar value, makes a `DateTime` from it if needed, and does a year-based `diff`.  So that part works.

But `age` does not automatically populate.  I get the following entries in the core log file, when I enter the `age` field:

> [2016-11-02 17:57:18] request.INFO: Matched route "app_remote_router".
>   {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"Casebox\RpcBundle\Controller\RpcApiController::routeAction","coreName":"demotwo","_route":"app_remote_router"},"request_uri":"http://192.168.33.3.xip.io/c/demotwo/remote/router"}
>   []
>
> [2016-11-02 17:57:18] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token
>   from the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
>
> [2016-11-02 17:57:18] security.DEBUG: User was reloaded from a user
>   provider.
>   {"username":"root","provider":"Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider"}
>   []
>
> [2016-11-02 17:57:18] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Function name
>   must be a string" at
>   /var/www/casebox/vendor/caseboxdev/core-bundle/src/Service/Browser.php
>   line 443 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
>   Function name must be a string at
>   /var/www/casebox/vendor/caseboxdev/core-bundle/src/Service/Browser.php:443)"}
>   []
>
> [2016-11-02 17:57:18] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the
>   session. {"key":"_security_main"} []

Inside `Browser.php`, I logged all the data I could find.  The line in question (presently 443) is unmodified from the original CaseBox distro, and it passes parameters to the target.  What I found is that it passes **all** the parameters, as an array.

So ultimately my guess is that my method needs to accept an array, and manually find `birthdate` and its value.

Answer (score 0):

My guess was partially correct.  I changed `calculateAge` like so:

```
function calculateAge(&$p) { 
    if (!empty($p['objFields']['birthdate'])) {
        $birthday = $p['objFields']['birthdate'];
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }

    //...proceed with calculation...
```

The second part was that my coworker fixed the CaseBox source file.  The relevant block was:

```
$method = explode('.', $fieldConfig['source']['fn']);
$class = new $method[0]();
$rez = $class->$method[1];
```

And the new code effectively casts the method name from an array to a string:

```
$method = explode('.', $fieldConfig['source']['fn']);
$class = new $method[0]();
$rez = $class->$method[1];
```